# Is there a PHP implementation that targets the JVM (akin to JRuby and Jython)?

Tags: java, php, jvm

How can I run PHP on JVM (akin to Jython and JRuby)? I am aware of the following:

[Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/), which appears to be <s>dead</s> alive and well.
Seems like I've been visiting the [wrong website](http://quercus.caucho.com/).

[webSphere sMash](http://www.projectzero.org/php/), that appears to have <s>no documentation</s> [been shutdown](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014910522&ps=25)

Is there a more mature project for this?

Comment: You may want to look at this: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/UsingPhp

Comment: Do you just want to write php code and have it run inside a java web server?

Comment: Unrelated: There is also "phpreboot" for the JVM. However syntactically it's more Javascript than PHP.

Comment: Quercus web site has moved again http://quercus.caucho.com/ Question has been updated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

AFAIK, [quercus](/questions/tagged/quercus) and P8 are the only two PHP compilers for the JVM, and you already ruled both of them out.

Although I think you are a little bit too harsh: Quercus had its latest release just 23 *days* ago. Calling it "dead" seems a little premature. And why do you need documentation for P8? *The whole point* is that it's just PHP. All the documentation you need is right there on PHP.Net.

Comment: Interesting, I've been visiting the wrong site. It seems like Quercus isn't dead after all. About the docs, they could at least tell me what's working and what's not, huh?

Comment: Could someone please post links to P8?

Comment: @mazin It's on my question. webSphere sMash IS P8

Comment: @NullUserException site is dead. Is project dead as well?

Comment: @mente It looks like it. See: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014910522&ps=25

Answer (score 5):

Another PHP compiler for JVM has born recently: https://github.com/dim-s/jphp

As author says:

**Goals**

JPHP is not a replacement for the Zend PHP engine or Facebook HHVM. We don't plan to implement the zend runtime libraries (e.g. Curl, PRCE, etc.) for JPHP. Our project started October 2013. There was a few reasons for that:

1. Ability to use java libraries in PHP
2. Upgrading performance via JIT and JVM
3. Replacing the ugly runtime library of Zend PHP with a better runtime library.
4. Using the PHP language not only on the web
5. Also: unicode for strings and threads